# Regex value comparison

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

I want to compare two numbers isolated from this sample data:

```
'gi|112807938|emb|CU075707.1|_Xenopus_tropicalis_finished_cDNA,_clone_TNeu129d01  C1:TCONS_00039972(XLOC_025068),_12.9045:32.0354,_Change:1.3118,_p:0.00025,_q:0.50752  C2:TCONS_00045925(XLOC_029835),_10.3694:43.8379,_Change:2.07985,_p:0.0004,_q:0.333824',
'gi|115528274|gb|BC124894.1|_Xenopus_laevis_islet-1,_mRNA_(cDNA_clone_MGC:154537_IMAGE:8320777),_complete_cds C1:TCONS_00080221(XLOC_049570),_17.9027:40.8136,_Change:1.18887,_p:0.00535,_q:0.998852  C2:TCONS_00092192(XLOC_059015),_17.8995:35.5534,_Change:0.990066,_p:0.0355,_q:0.998513',
'gi|118404233|ref|NM_001078963.1|_Xenopus_(Silurana)_tropicalis_pancreatic_lipase-related_protein_2_(pnliprp2),_mRNA  C1:TCONS_00031955(XLOC_019851),_0.944706:5.88717,_Change:2.63964,_p:0.01915,_q:0.998852 C2:TCONS_00036655(XLOC_023660),_2.31819:11.556,_Change:2.31757,_p:0.0358,_q:0.998513',
```

using the following regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my (@log_change, @largest_change);
        foreach (@intersect) {
            chomp;
            my @condition1_match = ($_ =~ /C1:.*?Change:(-?\d+\.\d+)|C1:.*?Change:(-?inf)/); # Sometimes the value is 'inf' or '-inf'. This allows either a numerical or inf value to be captured.
            my @condition2_match = ($_ =~ /C2:.*?Change:(-?\d+\.\d+)|C2:.*?Change:(-?inf)/);
            push @log_change, "@condition1_match\t@condition2_match";   
        }

    print Dumper (\@log_change);
```

Which gives this output:

```
          '1.3118   2.07985 ',
          '1.18887  0.990066 ',
          '2.63964  2.31757 ',
```

Ideally, within the same loop I now want to make a comparison between the values held in `@condition1_match` and `@condition2_match` such that the larger value is pushed onto a new array, unless comparing against a non numerical 'inf' in which case push the numerical value.

Something like this:

```
my (@log_change, @largest_change);
        foreach (@intersect) {
            chomp;
            my @condition1_match = ($_ =~ /C1:.*?Change:(-?\d+\.\d+)|C1:.*?Change:(-?inf)/);
            my @condition2_match = ($_ =~ /C2:.*?Change:(-?\d+\.\d+)|C2:.*?Change:(-?inf)/);
            push @log_change, "@condition1_match\t@condition2_match";
                unless ($_ =~ /Change:-?inf/) {
                    if (@condition1_match > @condition2_match) {
                        push @largest_change, @condition1_match;
                    }
                    else {
                        push @largest_change, @condition2_match;
                    }

                }

        }

    print Dumper (\@largest_change);
```

Which gives:

```
          '2.07985',
          undef,
          '0.990066',
          undef,
          '2.31757',
          undef,
```

as well as a lot of this error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $condition2_match[1] in join or string at intersect.11.8.pl line 114.
```

I'm unsure as to what exactly the error message means, as well as why I'm getting undef values in my `@largest_change`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've written your code, `@condition_match1` and `@condition_match2` will be created with 2 elements -- corresponding to the 2 capture groups in your regular expression -- each time there is a match. But one of these elements will always necessarily be `undef`, leading to the `uninitialized ...` warnings.

In this case, you can repair this program by putting the `|` inside the capture group:

```
my ($condition1_match) = ($_ =~ /C1:.*?Change:(-?\d+\.\d+|-?inf)/);
my ($condition2_match) = ($_ =~ /C2:.*?Change:(-?\d+\.\d+|-?inf)/);
```

so that there is a single capture group and the matching operation produces a list with a single, defined element.

In addition, the comparison

```
if (@condition1_match > @condition2_match) {
```

is probably not doing what you think it is doing. In Perl, a numerical comparison between two arrays is a comparison of array *lengths*. What you apparently mean to do is to compare the defined value in each of those arrays, so you would need to do something more cumbersome like:

```
my $condition1_match = $condition1_match[0] // $condition1_match[1];
my $condition2_match = $condition2_match[0] // $condition2_match[1];
if ($condition1_match > $condition2_match) {
    push @largest_change, $condition1_match;
} else {
    push @largest_change, $condition2_match;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really dense of me not to have known that '@array' > '@array' wouldn't work - would you be able to elaborate on the second part of your answer though - not entirely sure I understand what's going on there...

Comment: As in why are there two defined values in each array as opposed to one? Why does this compare elements[0] and [1] for each array? (Works a treat though!)

Comment: There is one defined value in each array because your regular expression can only generate one match: `/($expr1)|($expr2)/` will assign `$expr1` to `$1` if `$expr1` matches. Otherwise if will assign `$expr2` to `$2` if `$expr2` matches. The syntax `$a = $b // $c` means `$a = defined($b) ? $b : $c`, that is, assign `$b` if `$b` is defined, otherwise assign `$c`.