# Compare size of change rather than number

Tags: perl, string-comparison, logical-operators

I need to compare values from a list that represent log magnitudes of change:

```
      '1.3118   2.07985',
      '1.18887  0.990066',
      '2.63964  2.31757',
      '0.828566 1.03155',
      '-0.895715    -0.993696',
      '1.24353  1.35931',
      '1.2916   1.03409',
      '-0.747429    -1.18246',
      '1.30936  1.20244',
      '1.40537  1.27763',
      '-1.07762 -0.978337',
      '0.755268 0.837232',
      '0.919512 1.09517',
```

For each row, I want to make a comparison and store the value with the greatest magnitude of change. For example as I currently have it (thanks to help on this question [Regex value comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193243/regex-value-comparison)) this comparison:

```
if ($condition1_match > $condition2_match) {
    push @largest_change, $condition1_match;
}
```

would rightly value `-0.895715` as smaller than `-0.993696`. However I want to write comparison that recognises `-0.993696` as a higher fold change than `-0.895715`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the absolute values:

```
if (abs $condition1_match > abs $condition2_match) {
    push @largest_change, $condition1_match;
}
```

And of course the other way round, also:

```
elsif (abs $condition1_match < abs $condition2_match) {
    push @largest_change, $condition2_match;
}
```